# Initially hidden items not appearing in overflow menu after shown in EXTJS

Tags: extjs

I have a toolbar with buttons that are hidden by default, and then shown based on the user's privileges.  They appear and function after I call .show(), but do not appear in the overflow menu when the window is resized.  The items that are initially shown appear in the overflow menu correctly.

Any advice on how I can fix this problem?

Thanks

Edit: Here's the simplest example I could come up with that works with fiddle for the problem.  https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/877

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

var toolbar1 = Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    region: 'north',
    layout: {
            overflowHandler: 'Menu'
        },
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        emptyText: 'FIX ME'
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Test Lists',
        id: 'testListsButton',
        hidden: true
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'All Lists',
        id: 'allListsButton',
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Other Lists',
        id: 'otherListsButton',
        hidden: true
    },{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Email Lists',
        id: 'emailListsButton',
        hidden: true
    }]
});

Ext.getCmp('emailListsButton').show();
Ext.getCmp('otherListsButton').show();
Ext.getCmp('testListsButton').show();


    var viewPort = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'border',
        autoRender: true,
        items: [
            toolbar1
        ]
    });
})
```

Comment: Try to call [`doLayout`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.container.AbstractContainer-method-doLayout) on your toolbar after changing items visibility.

Comment: Tried it, but it didn't appear to do anything.  I also tried updateLayout().

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example?

Comment: Apparently I can't post an image until I have 10 reputation.  There's really nothing much to show code wise. The button's hidden config is set to true, and If (response.ROLE == 'Admin'){ button1.show(); }.  This makes the buttons appear on the toolbar without a problem.  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: try adding some code to your question using https://fiddle.sencha.com/

Comment: Added the fiddle code.

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-around.

I set the items to be visible initially, hide them before they're rendered, and then show them again when checking the user's privileges.  This properly displays the items in the overflow menu.

It looks like this is a bug, all be it a minor one.